# How to work with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

First time I am using momentjs for date&time problem. 
Here my problem is that I have to calculate date and maximum slots between the given time period.

TC1 : for 30 mins it is working fine, but 15 mins it is giving wrong result.

Here is my code :

```
let moment = require('moment');

let start_date= moment("2018-02-01");  
let end_date = moment("2018-02-02");  
let start = start_date.date();
let end = end_date.date(); 

const start_time = 12; // in 24hr 
const end_time = 13; // in 24hr 
const duration = 30;  
const duration_slot = (duration===5)?12:(duration===10)?6:(duration===15)?4:(duration===20)?3:(duration===30)?2:(duration===45)?1:0;
let slotNumber=1;
let counter=duration;

while(start < end){ // days count 
    let arslots = [];
     const nextDay = start_date.add(1, 'days');;

     for(let h=start_time;h<end_time;h++){ // checking start hours to maximum hours 

          let jsonObj = {};
          jsonObj.slotId = slotNumber++;

          nextDay.hours(h);
          nextDay.minutes();
          jsonObj.slot_start_time = nextDay.format();

          nextDay.hours(h);
          nextDay.minutes(duration);
          jsonObj.slot_end_time = nextDay.format();

          arslots.push(jsonObj);

          for (let m = 1; m < duration_slot; m++) {

            let jsonObj1 = {};
            jsonObj1.slotId = slotNumber++;

            nextDay.hours(h);
            nextDay.minutes(duration);
            jsonObj1.slot_start_time = nextDay.format();

            counter += counter;

            nextDay.hours(h);
            nextDay.minutes(counter);
            jsonObj1.slot_end_time = nextDay.format();

            arslots.push(jsonObj1);
          }
          counter = 0;
        }
    start++;
  }
 console.log(" ::: ", arslots)                          
}
```

output of 30 mins for 1 day is correct for the both slots 1 & 2.

```
[ { slotId: 1,
    slot_start_time: '2018-02-02T12:00:00+05:30',
    slot_end_time: '2018-02-02T12:30:00+05:30' },
  { slotId: 2,
    slot_start_time: '2018-02-02T12:30:00+05:30',
    slot_end_time: '2018-02-02T13:00:00+05:30' } ]
```

output of 15 mins for 1 day :

```
 [ { slotId: 1,
    slot_start_time: '2018-02-02T12:00:00+05:30',
    slot_end_time: '2018-02-02T12:15:00+05:30' },
  { slotId: 2,
    slot_start_time: '2018-02-02T12:15:00+05:30',
    slot_end_time: '2018-02-02T12:30:00+05:30' },
  { slotId: 3,
    slot_start_time: '2018-02-02T12:15:00+05:30',
    slot_end_time: '2018-02-02T13:00:00+05:30' },
  { slotId: 4,
    slot_start_time: '2018-02-02T12:15:00+05:30',
    slot_end_time: '2018-02-02T14:00:00+05:30' } ]
```

for the slotId 3 : time should be start with 12:45:00 and 
 for the slotId 4 : time should be start with 13:15:00

Can anyone help me ? Where I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `counter += counter` - you're *doubling* the counter instead of adding the "duration" each iteration.

Comment: It working dude thanks